# Snowflake: SQL compilation error: not a valid group by expression

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I'm trying to call a window function inside of a case statement, as such:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT properties.property_id
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE
                     WHEN units_count.unit_type = 'NORMAL' THEN units_count.unit_count
                 END) OVER (PARTITION BY properties.property_id),
            0)::INT AS normal_units_count
FROM units_count
JOIN properties ON units_count.property_id = properties.property_id
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
SQL compilation error: [IFF(UNITS_COUNT.UNIT_TYPE = 'NORMAL', UNITS_COUNT.UNIT_COUNT, SYSTEM$NULL_TO_FIXED(null))] is not a valid group by expression
```

I've tried adding a qualify clause to remove the `MAX()` function:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT properties.property_id
    COALESCE(CASE
                 WHEN units_count.unit_type = 'NORMAL' THEN units_count.unit_count
             END OVER (PARTITION BY properties.property_id),
            0)::INT AS normal_units_count
FROM units_count
JOIN properties ON units_count.property_id = properties.property_id
QUALIFY units_count.unit_count = MAX(units_count.unit_count) OVER (PARTITION BY properties.property_id)
```

The code executes, but the qualify clause results in unwanted filtering for other fields. Can I keep the existing logic (with `MAX()`) or do I need to include a qualify clause?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this point:  "...but the qualify clause results in unwanted filtering for other fields."

Answer (score 1):

The `DISTINCT` is in effect a grouping operation, but your MAX is a for every row with the `OVER` clause.

which implies as "basic SQL" this should work:

```
SELECT 
    p.property_id,
    MAX(IFF(uc.unit_type = 'NORMAL', uc.unit_count, 0)) as v1 max_units_count
FROM units_count AS uc
JOIN properties AS p 
    ON uc.property_id = p.property_id
GROUP BY 1
```

but as your "other fields" implies you are selecting other things and without knowing what/how you are doing that is hard to see what you are wanting todo.

also your `max(unit_count)` does not so much feel like it is a normal_unit_count.

But you example needs to pull in a second+ column of what you are wanting to do to see how they should be co-handled. But I would be inclined with zero information to suggest you use a CTE to find the per property_id the MAX unit_count and then join that result to a second read from your data. Because with zero insights to the other operations and how they could re-use that read,  I have experienced it is better to GROUP/JOIN then WINDOW(over partition)/ANYVALUE. But that is another option.

Thus (without testing) this might work:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT p.property_id
    ANYVALUE(COALESCE(MAX(CASE
                     WHEN uc.unit_type = 'NORMAL' THEN uc.unit_count
                 END) OVER (PARTITION BY p.property_id),
            0)::INT) AS normal_units_count
FROM units_count AS uc
JOIN properties AS p 
    ON uc.property_id = p.property_id
```